# How to deploy a flask socket io application on IIS server?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-socketio

**my use case is**

1. I am trying to build an API that takes images as input and does some
   image processing operations and return the output JSON back to the
   client.
2. Multiple clients can concurrently request Server and as the server
   does take 2 to 3 minutes time to process.
3. Initially I thought of a normal flask Application, where client
   would poll the server for a response on a timely basis
4. But as Flask-SocketIO can respond back to the client event-based, I
   want to use Flask-SocketIO
5. As the other APIs in my project are hosted on IIS, I wanted to use
   the same IIS as the hosting server

**my questions are**

1. Can I use Flask-SocketIO for my use case, where API takes 2 to 3
   minutes to respond back
2. If not IIS, how to deploy flask-socketIO on
   the windows machine, I have gone through the documentation but I did
   not find any deployment strategy for hosting it on windows machine
3. The best way to achieve concurrency in this case

Thanks in advance
Prasad.